# Running sqldeveloper is throwing error "cannot find javaw.exe"

Tags: java, oracle-sqldeveloper, javaw

I installed sqldeveloper zip file in my system (windows 7)/. As soon as I clicked on sqldeveloper.exe, its throwing error "Windows cannot find C:/Program Files(x86)/Java/ jre1.8.0_31/bin/javaw.exe"

I dont understand why its giving error which has this path. In my system, I had installed JDK-1.7 64 bits. Previously I had installed JDK-1.8 32 bits. After removing JDK-1.8, I installed JDK-1.7 and changed the path variable also. Everything is working fine with java in my system. But SQLDeveloper is not being run. Please help.

Comment: Well, check the settings of sqldeveloper and the value of the java_home envitonment variable.

Comment: Is `JAVA_HOME` set correctly?

Answer (score 0):

You need to set your `JAVA_HOME` correctly.

In **Windows**:

Go to,

> System --> Advance system settings --> Advanced --> Environment
>   Variables

If you don't have **JAVA_HOME**, then add the variable and set the value

For example,

```
C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_71
```

In ***NIX**:

```
export JAVA_HOME=/<your_location>
```